# cannot test network call inside xcode project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

I'm new at ios Unitesting and this is the first time i'm actually doing it.

My Application is using a framework that is doing some network calls,

I'm trying to test the business logic of the framework by calling one of these function
but the function just passes past the actual call, and never goes into the callback.

here is the actual function inside the framework i'm trying to check >

```
func initSDK () {
        let launchParams: [String:String] = [
            kAWSDKUrl:  WhiteLabeler.localizedStringForKey(key: "baseSDKUrl", comment: "-", defaultValue: "https://isr-lap-tst2.americanwell.com:8443/"),
            kAWSDKKey:  WhiteLabeler.localizedStringForKey(key: "SDKserviceKeyForIos", comment: "-", defaultValue: "TriageApp"),
            kAWSDKBundleID: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
        ]

        AWSDKService.initialize(withLaunchParams: launchParams) {[weak self] (success, error) in
            if success {
                self?.myPresenter?.onSDKInitlized()
                self?.didSdkInitilized = true
            } else {
                self?.myPresenter?.onError(errorText: error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
            }
        }
    }
```

and here is my test case:

```
import XCTest
@testable import TriageFramework

class Virtual_First_Tests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
    }

    func testExample1() {
        let homeInteractor: HomeInteractor = HomeInteractor();
        var didInitlized = homeInteractor.didSdkInitilized
        homeInteractor.initSDK()

        sleep(2)

        didInitlized = homeInteractor.didSdkInitilized
        XCTAssertTrue(didInitlized)


    }
```

but it always fails as it never goes into the callback for success or fail.
What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do network calls inside your unit tests. Unit test are meant to test single classes isolated. So you should stub you network call or [inject your dependencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) into the class that you are testing (In your case `HomeInteractor`). Also your unit test needs to run fast, doing network calls inside your unit test will do the opposite.

[Here](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/UnitTest.html) there is a post that will help you to create good unit tests.

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer, can u maybe give some code example of what u mean for the stubbing the network call ? (most of my application is just calling this calls from the framework, so if i wont test this i wont have anything else to test)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to point out about the code you want to test:

- It uses an **implicit dependency on a third party**, the aws sdk service. The behaviour of a component with implicit dependencies is harder to test, because you can't control them directly
- It makes an **asynchronous call**. That is, part of the behaviour happens in the closure callback of the `initialize` method. This means the tests will need to take into account the fact they have to wait for the closure to be called.

As [Enrique Bermúdez notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54689869/cannot-test-network-call-inside-xcode-project/54824419#answer-54689974), you should always avoid to make network calls in unit or integration tests. Hitting a server makes the tests run slower, and tests should be [fast](https://pragprog.com/magazines/2012-01/unit-tests-are-first) so you can have a quick feedback. On top of that you want your tests to be predictable, but making a network call could fail for any number of reasons, like a time out, the server being down, or a drop in connectivity.

The best way I know of insulating yourself from both the dependency on a server and the third party code for the AWS SDK is to put a protocol in front of it, and replace it with a test double.

```swift
protocol AWSSDKWrapper {

  static func initialize() // this should actually match the signature of the
                           // initialize method on AWSSDKService, but I don't
                           // know how it looks like
}

extension AWSSDKService: AWSSDKWrapper { }
```

You can then inject the dependency on AWS in the `init` of your type.

```swift
class HomeInteractor {

  private let awsSDKWrapper: AWSSDKWrapper

  init(awsSDKWrapper: AWSSDKWrapper = AWSSDKService.self) {
    self.awsSDKWrapper = awsSDKWrapper
  }

  func initSDK () {
    let launchParams: [String:String] = // ...

    awsSDKWrapper.initialize(withLaunchParams: launchParams) {[weak self] (success, error) in
      if success {
        self?.myPresenter?.onSDKInitlized()
        self?.didSdkInitilized = true
      } else {
        self?.myPresenter?.onError(errorText: error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now you have a layer of abstraction in between both the 3rd party and the network request it makes. We can build our own [test double](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html) to control the behaviour in the tests.

```swift
struct AWSSDKStub: AWSSDKWrapper {

  let result: Result<Bool, NSError>  // I'm assuming the type of error the AWSSDK
                                     // callback returns is NSError.
                                     // I'm also assuming you have Swift 5 Result
                                     // available, if you don't check this Gist for
                                     // a lightweight drop-in replacement

  init(succeeding: Bool) {
    self.result = .success(succeeding)
  }

  init(error: NSError) {
    self.result = .failure(error)
  }

  func initialize(/* again not sure how the arguments look like */) {
    switch result {
      case .success(let succeeded): callback(succeeded)
      case .failure(let error): error
    }
  }
}
```

Depending on what behaviour you want to test you may or may not want to add a probe value to capture the launchParams passed to initialize.

Now let's use this object to control the behaviour in the tests.

```swift
func testAWSSDKInitializeSuccess() {
  let homeInteractor = HomeInteractor(awsSDWWrapper: AWSSDKStub(succeeding: true))

  // Because the test is asynchronous we need to setup the expectation _before_
  // calling its method.
  // 
  // More here: https://www.mokacoding.com/blog/xctest-closure-based-expectation/
  let predicate = NSPredicate(block: { any, _ in
    return (any as? HomeIterator)?.didSdkInitilized == true
  })
  _ = self.expectation(for: predicate, evaluatedWith: homeIterator, handler: .none)

  homeIntera.initSDK()

  waitForExpectations(timeout: 1, handler: .none)
}
```

The beauty of this approach is that we can also write tests for the case in which the AWS SDK initialization returns false or an error. We couldn't have done this if we had kept hitting the actual AWS endpoint, as we don't have control on how it responds.

#### Additional Notes

Wrapping third party dependencies in protocols that expose only the API our apps are interested in is valuable not only because it allows us to provide test doubles and better test how the code interacts with the dependencies, but also because it allows us to not have to change our code if the dependency changes, only the wrapper. See also [dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

Calling a wrapper protocol `Wrapper` is a smell. Ideally you'd use a name that captures the subset of the 3rd party functionality you are using.

The test we've written check whether `didSdkInitilized` is set to `true`. The question I'd like to ask you is "is this the actual behaviour of `HomeInteractor`, or is it just an implementation detail?" It's hard to answer without knowing more about what HomeIterator should be doing, but my guess is that `didSdkInitilized` is only an implementation detail, and the real behaviour of the method is to call `onSDKInitlized()` or `onError(errorText:)` on its presenter.

It's always better to write test focused on the behaviour not the implementation details. Tests focused on implementation details get in your way when you want to refactor the code, i.e. change the its implementation without changing how it behaves. Test focused on the behaviour help you in the long run.

In your case a possible way to test whether if `HomeInteractor` calls the presenter when the third party SDK is successfully initialized is to use a test double for the presenter and to then check if its methods have been called. More about this approach [here](https://www.mokacoding.com/blog/testing-delegates-in-swift-with-xctest/#other-delegate-tests).

---

Hope this helps. Hit me up on Twitter at [@mokagio](https://twitter.com/mokagio) if you'd like to chat more about testing in Swift.